# Right Align elements in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

How to **Right Align** elements of a **Horizontal** `LinearLayout` without having to convert it to a `RelativeLayout` or wrapping it's elements inside another Layouts.

this is the layout params i'm using inside the layout:

```
    // this is for some elements(ImageButtons)
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ineer_ver = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.RIGHT);
                        lp_ineer_ver.bottomMargin = 2;
                        lp_ineer_ver.leftMargin = 3;
                        lp_ineer_ver.topMargin = 2;


// this is for others(TextViews, Buttons)
LinearLayout.LayoutParams elements_params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)text1.getLayoutParams();    
                       elements_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                       elements_params.leftMargin = 3;
                       elements_params.weight = 1;
                       text1.setLayoutParams(elements_params);
```

Comment: try to set layout_gravity="right" pogrammatically: like this `params.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this..

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ineer_ver = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                lp_ineer_ver.bottomMargin = 2;
                lp_ineer_ver.leftMargin = 3;
                lp_ineer_ver.topMargin = 2;
                lp_ineer_ver.gravity= Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Comment: i don't know what was the difference :D

Comment: Even i dont know... But sometimes we have to throw stones like this.. :D . But credit should goes to the person who commented on your post. Just i wrote his concept programatically.